# Trouble with ::before,how to apply differently depending on contents of <div>?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Let's say I have:

```
<p>Paragraph.</p>
<div class="note">Naked Note Div.</div>
<div class="note">
  <p>Paragraph in Note DIV.</p>
  <p>Second Paragraph in Note DIV.</p>
</div>
<div>NON Note Naked Div.</div>
<div>
  <p>Paragraph in NON None DIV.</p>
</div>
```

I would then like to get the output:

```
 Paragraph.
 NOTE: Naked Note Div.
 NOTE: Paragraph in Note DIV.
 Second Paragraph in Note DIV.
 NON Note Naked Div.
 Paragraph in NON None DIV.
```

I have tried to use pseudo class ::before to achieve this but the fact that some divs have paragraphs inside and some don't makes it surprisingly difficult, at least for newbie me.

With: CSS `.note::before {content: "NOTE: ";}` I get:

```
 Paragraph.
 NOTE: Naked Note Div.
 NOTE:
 Paragraph in Note DIV.
 Second Paragraph in Note DIV.
```

With CSS `.note :first-child::before {content: "NOTE: ";}` I get:

```
 Paragraph.
 Naked Note Div.
 NOTE: Paragraph in Note DIV.
 Second Paragraph in Note DIV.
```

Is there any way to fix this with just CSS? That is not using a preprocessor or jquery or such.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with the `:has()` selector

```css
.note:not(:has(*)):before, /* when it has nothing select the note element*/
.note:has(*) :first-child:before { /* when it has something select the first child*/
  content:"Note: ";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph.</p>
<div class="note">Naked Note Div.</div>
<div class="note">
  <p>Paragraph in Note DIV.</p>
  <p>Second Paragraph in Note DIV.</p>
</div>
<div>NON Note Naked Div.</div>
<div>
  <p>Paragraph in NON None DIV.</p>
</div>
```

Until better support for `:has()` you can use float:

```css
.note::before { 
  content:"Note:";
  color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph.</p>
<div class="note">Naked Note Div.</div>
<div class="note">
  <p>Paragraph in Note DIV.</p>
  <p>Second Paragraph in Note DIV.</p>
</div>
<div>NON Note Naked Div.</div>
<div>
  <p>Paragraph in NON None DIV.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @isherwood because some divs does not have a <p>

Comment: @EntryLevel99 you are commenting on the wrong answer